# JHipster with jasperreports

Tags: java, gradle, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

I'm tying to integrate jaspereports into jHipster, and all I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException
```

, when I try to:

```
JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
```

I guess I miss some dependencies in my build.gradle. I can't find an example on the internet. Is there any examples or guides to do this ?

Comment: You should add `net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:x.y.z` dependency. Sample: `dependencies {
    compile "net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.5.0"
}`

Comment: That worked, thanks